# Sift through three lists and write final list

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have this problem with 3 lists, 1 2-D and 2 1-D. The 2-D list 'intervals' consists of [time, point1, point2], the 1-D list 'points' consists of [point] and the 1-D list 'times' consists of [time].

At each "time", multiple items in [point] can lie within the range [point1,point2]. As seen from the list 'intervals', at "time = 1", "points" 2,3, and 4 lie within the range "point1" to "point2". At "time = 4", there are 4 sets of [point1, point2] and various items lie within these ranges.

I am attempting to check if and when items from "point" lie within the range [point1, point2], and assigning a 1 or 0 based on whether they are present in the range or not. Then checking if there are multiple sets of [point1, point2] at the same "time", and if there are, making sure that all occurences of "point" in the range [point1, point2] are captured and copied into a final list. So, the final list should be a 32*3 list, capturing all occurrences of "point" in the range[point1, point2] at all "times". I am going wrong with the last bit. Any help with the following code would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import math
import random
import numpy as np

intervals = [[1,1,5],[2,1,3],[2,2,4],[3,2,4],[3,3,6],[3,6,8],[4,5,9],[4,3,10],[4,6,8],[4,5,10]] 
points = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
times = [1,2,3,4] 
count = []
new_array = []
final_array = []


for t in times:
    for j in range(len(intervals)):
        if intervals[j][0] == t:
            for i in range(len(points)):
                print('t=', t, 'j=', j, 'i=', i, intervals[j][0])   
                if points[i] >= intervals[j][1] and points[i] < intervals[j][2]:
                    count.append([t, 1, points[i]])
                else:
                    count.append([t, 0, points[i]])

len_count = len(count) - 4

count = np.array(count)

for k in range(4,len_count,1):
    y = k-4
    z = k+4
    print(y,z)      
    if count[y][0] == count[z][0] and count[y][1] != count[z][1]:
        if count[y][1] == 0:
            count[y][1] = 1
        else:
            count[z][1] = 1  
    new_array.append([count[y][0], count[y][1], count[y][2]])

new_array = np.array(new_array)

np.savetxt('new_array.txt', new_array)

len_new_count = len(new_array)-8


for t in times:
    for k in range(8,len_new_count,1):
        r = k-8
        s = k+8
        print(r,s)
        if new_array[k][0] == t:
            if new_array[k][0] == new_array[r][0]:
                new_array[r][:] = new_array[k][:]
                k = k+8
                final_array.append([new_array[k][0], new_array[k][1], new_array[k][2]])
```

The output is missing out data for "time" 1 and 2 and printing data for "time" 3 and "4" twice.

Thanks!

Comment: It makes it much easier to work out what's going on if you name things usefully. So instead of `a`,`b` and `x` use something like `intervals`, `times` and `points`.

Comment: And then things like `for t in len(x)` is awkward when has nothing to do with time (but `j` does). Something like `for point in points:` and `for time in times:` makes following code much easier, especially if you don't need the index of the value you're working with.

Comment: Thanks Trengot! Will make these changes - I am sorry, I am a novice programmer and I know the code put above is not optimal in any way, but will try to be more judicious going forward. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, have a look through https://robot.bolink.org/ebooks/Clean%20Code%20-%20A%20Handbook%20of%20Agile%20Software%20Craftsmanship%20By%20Robert%20C%20Martin.pdf It helped me a huge amount.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Trengot! Have made those changes - will keep looking and make sure that future code is more readable. Thanks!